# Exception raised while trying to access facebook API with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am trying with Facebook API with codeigniter. While I am trying with get some basic information about the users like

```
$this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email,user_hometown,user_education_history,user_birthday&perms=publish_stream,create_event');
```

I am getting exception like

```
Exception: Unknown fields: user_hometown,user_education_history,user_birthday
```

But the documentation says it is fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know anything about codeigniter. Do you know if that call is using the official PHP SDK or does codeigniter have it's own set of APIs?

Do you know if it's hitting the Graph API or the old REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "user_" prefix on "hometown", "education", and "birthday". You also don't need "_history" on "education". Try this in your API call instead:

```
'me?fields=id,name,link,email,hometown,education,birthday'
```